# Command-line video concatenation and recompression?

Tags: linux, command-line, video, editing, encoding

What is the best CLI tool (preferably Linux based) that will allow concatenating video files, and also compressing them on the client-side for YouTube upload?

Answer (score 3):

My best bet is ffmpeg. It is powerful enough to do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can merge 2 video files with this command line:

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy video1.avi video2.avi -o output.avi
```

Comment: mencoder is rather hard to find... The Google hits lead you to MPlayer, and when you download it's actually called SMPlayer. Any ideas where to find mencoder, really?

Comment: For me, mencoder is in the mencoder ubuntu package.

Answer (score 2):

mencoder, transcode and ffmpeg are your friends (amongst others)
you could also use vlc in CLI mode (AFAIK uses ffmpeg) or mplayer (mencoder)

Comment: VLC tends to supply its own ffmpeg build internally, so it's worth trying separately if ffmpeg isn't quite doing what you want.